# Inserting (string, object * ) into hash table (C++)

Tags: c++, hashmap

This question is an offgrowth of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645913/inserting-objects-into-hash-table-c) on creating a hash table to store string keys and pointers as data. I'm getting a seg fault post-construction when I try to add entries to my hash table. I'm still very confused about what syntax is appropriate.

I currently have (thanks to previous posters):

```
// Simulation.h
#include <ext/hash_map>
using namespace __gnu_cxx;
...
typedef struct { size_t operator()( const string& str ) const 
  { return __gnu_cxx::__stl_hash_string( str.c_str() ); } } strhash;

struct eqstr {
  bool operator()(string s1, string s2) const {
   return ( s1.compare(s2) == 0 );
  }
};
....
hash_map< string, Strain *, strhash, eqstr > strainTable;
```

In my Simulation constructor, I have:

```
// Simulation.cpp
Simulation::Simulation() : ... {
  string MRCA;
  for ( int b = 0; b < SEQ_LENGTH; b++ ) {
    int randBase = rgen.uniform(0,NUM_BASES); 
    MRCA.push_back( BASES[ randBase ] );
  }
  Strain * firstStrainPtr;
  firstStrainPtr = new Strain( idCtr, MRCA, NUM_STEPS );
  strainTable[ MRCA ]= firstStrainPtr; // <-- Hash table initialization
  ....
}
```

This seems to work fine. I get a seg fault when the following insertion is attempted:

```
void Simulation::updateSimulation( double t ) {
   ....
   // Add mutants to liveStrains() and strainTable
   vector< Strain * >::const_iterator mItr = newMutants.begin();
   for ( mItr = newMutants.begin(); mItr != newMutants.end(); ++mItr ) // for each mutant in deme
{
  string mutantSeq = ( *mItr )->getSequence();
  cout << "mutantSeq is " << mutantSeq << endl; // <-- This is fine
  liveStrains.push_back( *mItr );
  strainTable[ mutantSeq ] = *mItr; // <-- Seg fault happens here
}
  newMutants.clear();
  ....  
}
```

Reading the third note on the operator[] in the [SGI documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html), this seems like it should be fine. What's wrong? I'm thinking of switching to a map container just to save debugging time...

**Update**

Something about the initialization seems wrong. When I get to

```
strainTable[ mutantSeq ] = *mItr;
```

the debugger reports "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and jumps to

```
_Node* __first = _M_buckets[__n];
```

of hashtable.h.

Comment: Why not use std::string rather than your own strhash?

Comment: I thought SGI did not allow string types for the hash...

Comment: This probably won't fix it, but in eqstr, your operator() should take const string&, otherwise you will be making string copies all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a diagnosis approach, you actually have 2 instructions executed on the line:

1. Lookup in `strainTable`, which returns a reference
2. Dereferencing the iterator
3. Assignation of a value to the reference

Here you might want to take a `Divide and Conquer` approach:

```
  strainTable[ mutantSeq ] = *mItr; // <-- Seg fault happens here
```

Becomes

```
  Strain*& aReference = strainTable[ mutantSeq ];
  Strain* const aPtr = *mItr;
  aReference = aPtr;
```

(which is a general advice)

On which line does the seg fault occur ? Would it be possible to have the 10 first frames of the stack ?

While looking up Google, I came up this [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2005-08/msg00506.html), which suggests there might be issues with the `hash_map`...

You might be better off using the [unordered_map](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/classstd_1_1tr1_1_1unordered__map.html) if possible, as it's clearly indicated that no time will be taken fixing the `hsah_map` viewed as a legacy container (and this was 2005...). Note that it should be available if you use GCC 4.x (not sure for 3.x)

The main advantage is that the `hash` structure and `comparison predicate` already work for `std::string` so you don't even have to implement them yourself :)

All you have to do, therefore, if you have this in your compiler, is to write this:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, Strain*> strain_hash_map;
```

Comment: Thanks, Matthieu. Saw your comment after my edit. I think I will switch to the TR1 unordered_map. I hope it's more friendly.

Comment: As a new programmer, I also appreciate your explaining useful heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any bad with this code. The error has to have in another place. Maybe the value of (*mItr)->getSequence(), that is giving an invalid string, or something like that.

As an optimization, the operator() could take string const& instead of just string's.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the value in the debugger, and (*mItr)->getSequence() is behaving as it should. The liveStrains.push_back(...) also works. I edited the description of the problem with some more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

The embarrassing "solution" is that I discovered I had not declared the full size of a two-dimensional array in the class header file. When I initialized the array in the constructor, it happened to overwrite some of the space for the hash table.

Thanks to the suggestions here, I've now moved to a std::tr1::unordered_map!